# Django - Include data from foreignkey in admin list_display function

Tags: django, django-models

I have two models and one admin model:

```
class Person(models.Model):

    firstname = models.CharField(maxlength=50)
    surname = models.CharField(maxlength=50)

class Friends(models.Model):

    person1 = models.ForeignKey("Person")
    person2 = models.ForeignKey("Person")
    friendship_made = models.DateField()

class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["firstname", "surname"]
```

I want to show the friend of the person in the list_display. I know if I had the foreignkey field in the `Person` model I could use the double underscore to reference it e.g. `person2__surname`.  But not sure how to do it when thr foreign key is in the other table.

In my system one person can only be friends with one person at a time so it would be better if the foreignkey was in the person model but I want to store extra info about the friendship such as the date it was made (firendship_made) so this is why I've put it in a seperate model.  Any advise?  If I have to change my models to get the best result I don't mind.

Answer (score 10):

You need to create something like this in your FriendAdmin class:

```
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (..., 'get_reviews')

    def get_reviews(self, obj):
        return obj.book.review
    get_reviews.short_description = 'Review'
```

Comment: This method works nicely for displaying these related fields in the list view, however Django doesn't seem to want to sort the table by these type of fields which is a bit annoying.

Comment: @jrwagz You can do `get_reviews.admin_order_field = 'book__review__some_review_field'`

Answer (score 0):

This code isn't complete - you've got two ForeignKeys from `Friends` to `Person`, so at least one of them will need a `related_name` attribute to prevent clashes. The code simply won't run as it is.

If a Person can only be friends with one other person, you should use a `OneToOneField` rather than a `ForeignKey`. Then, you can simply refer to `my_person.friend1.person1.surname`, where `my_person` is the Person you starting with, and `friend1` is the `related_name` value I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Thans for your Answer uvasal (it was very helpful) but this code has invalid syntax

you need:
return '%s'%(obj.book.review,)
or
return '%s' % obj.book.review