# ModelAdmin, foreign key relation chain

Tags: django, modeladmin

**I wonder if it is possible in a clean way to print a foreignkey chain in ModelAdmin:**

Image we have this structure:

```
class Ma(models.Model):
      fa = models.EmailField()

class Mb(models.Model):
      fb = models.ForeignKey('Ma')

class Mc(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
      fc = models.ForeignKey('Mb')
```

Now with ModelAdmin:

**Edit: (This is not valid)**

```
class McAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     list_display = ('name', 'fc__fb__fa',)
```

Or how can I solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5373339/203535) answer:

You can create a method on your McAdmin class that returns these nested Foreign Key values:

```
class McAdmin(admin.modelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'get_email_foreign_foreign_key')

    def get_email_foreign_foreign_key(self, obj):
        return '%s' % obj.fc.fb.fa
```